# Combining functions (AND)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a question regarding combining functions.

My purpose is to apply two functions at the same time. Basically, I want to cut my dataset for extreme values by looking for the 5% quantile at the lowest part of the dataset and the top % at the other end.

```
df = df[df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.05)]
```

gets me values that are above the 5% quantile

```
df = df[df.temperature <= df.temperature.quantile(.95)]
```

gets me all the values that are below the 95% quantile.

My current problem is that

```
df = df[df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.05)]
df = df[df.temperature <= df.temperature.quantile(.95)]
```

works but it's not precise because the 2nd function builds on top of the previous cut. So how can I cut both at once?

```
df = df[df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.05) & <=    df.temperature.quantile(.95)]
```

does not work.

Thanks for support!

**Solved:**

df = df[(df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.05)) & (df.temperature <= (df.temperature.quantile(.95)))]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses around the conditions due to operator precedence:

```
f = df[(df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.05)) & (df.temperature <= df.temperature.quantile(.95))]
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) show that `>=` has lower precedence than `&` so you need the parentheses, besides your code should have raised an ambiguous error.

code style wise it is more readable to have your conditions as variables so I would rewrite it to this:

```
low_limit = df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.05)
upper_limit = df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.95)
```

then your filtering becomes:

```
df[(low_limit) & (upper_limit)]
```

You could optionally change

```
low_limit = df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.05)
```

to

```
low_limit = (df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.05))
```

so you don't need the parentheses in the filtering

Comment: This was almost right, but I could fix it: df = df[(df.temperature >= df.temperature.quantile(.05)) & (df.temperature <= (df.temperature.quantile(.95)))]